# ModelMapper mapping from multi flat object to hierarchy object

Tags: java, modelmapper

I have a situation, where I need to map multi objects (in a flat structure) into one object (an  hierarchy object) in Java using [ModelMapper](http://modelmapper.org/).

For example,

```
class Person{
    String name;
    int age;
}

class Address{
    int streetSumber;
    String streetName;
    String city;
}

class Phone{
    String type;
    String number;    
}
```

What I want to get out from the model mapper is something like

```
class PersonDTO{

    String name;
    int age;

    class AddressDTO{
        int streetSumber;
        String streetName;
        String city;
    }

    class PhoneDTO{
        String type;
        String number;    
    }
}
```

Is there a way to simple achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You must create a `PersonWrapper`

```
class PersonWrapper {
  Person person;
  Address address;
  Phone phone;
}
```

and map PersonWrapper to PersonDTO, for example

```
PropertyMap<PersonWrapper, PersonDTO> orderMap = new PropertyMap<Order, OrderDTO>() {
  protected void configure() {
    map().setName(source.getPerson().getName());
    ....
  }
};
```